# Draw drawable on ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

I have a custom subclass of imageView that I can pan and zoom. How can I put on top of it other image (from drawable) that will pan and move with the imageView like it stuck to it?

Comment: So you want to make a drawable that consist of two other drawables?

Comment: just use another `ImageView` and just set it location above the other `ImageView`

Comment: At first I added another ImageView on top of first. But the problem is that I need to recalculate everything so the ImageView move together with the custom ImageView. I am looking for better solution.

Comment: Hey K-ballo, tried that. If it consist of 2 images it stretches them to bigger one. That is not what I need.

Comment: I would add to this custom ImageView listener `onTransformationUpdate`, then on every transformation update I would apply it to views I want. Of course you have to do some math calculations.